# Expansion of constant-size sets

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, expanders

My question refers to the expansion of constant size sets of an expander graph.
Suppose we are given an expander graph with Cheeger constant $\alpha$.
What can be said about the edge expansion of sets of size, say 100?

Is it true, that the relative expansion of a set, w.r.t. the set size always has a
decaying profile - so that constant size sets expand much more rapidly than the overall graph expansion?

While there is nothing to stop constant-size sets from having just poor overall expansion value (equal to the minimal expansion over all sets) by definition, is it possible to show such a property?

Comment: Hi Lior. I merged your new account with the previous one. I would suggest that you register your account to avoid creating new ones and to have ability to edit your posts later.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? If you just follow the definitions, there is nothing to prevent an expander graph with expansion $\alpha$ to have a constant-sized set with expansion $\alpha$. Maybe your question is about random graphs, or existing explicit families?

Comment: Thank you MCH.  Modified question following your comment.